# Web Parts and Offering Files For Download?

Tags: sharepoint, download, web-parts

Can anyone suggest the best way to offer a file for download within a SharePoint web part?  The file will be dynamically created on request, but I still need to end up with the standard page being displayed as well as the file being downloaded.

Comment: What do you mean by 'standard page'?

Comment: I mean whatever the page displays when not handling the file download.  For example, I have several tables on the page, and offer an 'export' option which hands the user the data as a .csv.  However, I don't want the user to end up on a blank page et al.  All of the examples I have seen for this only handle the file download and assume the file download is occuring from a dedicated page which is disposable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I dynamically added an iFrame to the web part during the reload after the user chooses the 'Export' option, and within that loaded a standard .aspx page which handles the sending. This got around the issue of having to send a Response.End

Answer (score 0):

The basic ingredients of this example are quite simple and can be found in a Microsoft article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/directory/article.asp?ID=KB;EN-US;q306654&lex).

The Microsoft article includes the following code snippet:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  //Set the appropriate ContentType.
  Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  //Get the physical path to the file.
  string FilePath = MapPath("acrobat.pdf");
  //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
  Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
  Response.End();
}
```

That should help you.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the problem with that is the 'Response.End' - you can't do anything other than send the file and thats that.  I need to send the file and display a normal page.