# Response.WriteFile in SharePoint webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a webpart in which I have to provide links to files. One requirement is to that the user should be able to click the file link and a file "Save As" dialog should appear allowing the user to download the file to their PC.

I've tried using `Response.WriteFile` but it is not working with a SharePoint webpart so now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is generated dynamically and not in a library, you can see this similar post here: [Web Parts and Offering Files For Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404560/web-parts-and-offering-files-for-download)

Basically the described solution consists in adding a link to a standard aspx page on your web part, and let that aspx page handle the file download (because you can't use Response.End in your webpart)

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside a web part you need to reference the HTTPContext instead of the response object directly.

i.e.. HTTPContext.Current.Response.Write("Something");